# Tópicos antigos, trazidos a home, deveriam ter alguma diferenciação

Tags: debate

Tenho uma sugestão referente as perguntas evidenciadas pelo bot "Comunidade".

Como sabemos, o bot pega perguntas antigas sem solução definida e coloca na home.

Algo que acho muito confuso e incômodo é que todos os dias eu acesso tais perguntas "sem querer" e inclusive perco tempo respondendo.

O incômodo é justamente porque cria essa confusão. Pelo fato de estar na home,  logo imagino que seja uma pergunta nova.

A sugestão é separar, de alguma forma, os tópicos antigos trazidos de volta a home, dos demais que são postagens novas.

Se puder pelo menos, colocar a data original da pergunta juntamente ao título, acredito que melhoraria muito.

[edição respondendo comentários e respostas]

Referente a perda de tempo mencionada, vou citar um exemplo prático para que entendam.

A maioria das questões que eu peguei e comentei ou respondi, estavam simplesmente abandonadas. Os meus posts não fizeram a menor diferença pois na maioria dos casos ficam pendentes de feedback do AP.
Então vc vai lendo outros comentários, todos também, como eu, pedindo um feedback para entender a pergunta. E todos de meses atrás. O AP, não dá resposta alguma, ou seja, simplesmente abandonado, sem condições de dar uma resposta. Puro lixo. Não tira-se proveito de nada e tampouco aprende-se nada com nada.

Muitas dessas questões antigas são passivas de fechamento, inclusive eu já passei isso diversas vezes em responder uma pergunta antiga, dessas abandonadas por falta de feedback do AP  que o bot traz para a home. Logo em seguida alguém fecha, geralmente por falta de conteúdo sobre a pergunta.

Entendem o que é a perda de tempo em dar atenção a tais tópicos?

Por isso, discordo de respostas aqui que diz que tira-se bom proveito mesmo de situações como essas.

Ok, podemos evitar isso prestando mais atenção. Se for um post editado pelo bot, então evite o tópico. Pronto! Morreu o assunto!

É assim? Obviamente que eu entendo, mas e outros usuários? Vão sempre passar pelo mesmo "problema" pois quem aqui sabe das funções são os experientes que vivem isso aqui 24 horas.. e mesmo um usuário como eu que tem uma certa familiaridade me deparo com situações confusas em relação as ferramentas e usabilidade em geral.

Onde eu quero chegar, é **tornar as ferramentas e funções do SO mais amigáveis e intuitivas**.

Destaco em negrito pois esse é o intuito principal desse debate, ok?

O @Bigown mostrou que tem um link que lista apenas as perguntas novas. Ok, isso já é bom, mas veja, eu nem sabia que existia tal link. E vocês acham mesmo que outros usuários comuns, que assim como eu acessam o site exporadicamente, vão saber chegar nesse link?

Enfim, o que coloco é meramente uma sugestão para melhoria de funcionamento do site. Para tornar o site mais fácil e intuitivo. Se for aceito ou não, não é a minha preocupação. A preocupação é encontrar uma solução.

Desculpe não esclarecer antes. No momento em que abri esse tópico eu até cheguei a escrever mas apaguei porque ficou extenso e resumi até chegar nesse formato anterior a edição. Normalmente poucos lêem textos longos e também são difíceis de interpretar especialmente quando o assunto em foco desvia-se um pouco pois para explicar envolve exemplos, etc, e isso desvia a atenção do assunto em foco.

Por isso achei melhor esperar os comentários para então, conforme perguntem, eu vou respondendo.

**Datas dos tópicos**

Ok, após todo esse blá bla blá, alguém dirá o mesmo que o bigown, sobre ver a data ao entrar no tópico.

Tipo, dãnm~ .. precisa ser um gênio para descobrir isso.. rsrs

O foco aqui é referente a confusão na usabilidade do site.

Coisas que tornam confusas, dentro do contexto desse debate,

1. Os tópicos na home não mostram data.
   Pelo fato de estar na home, o usuário/visitante já imagina que se trata de alvo novo, recente e ativo.
2. As datas abrviadas dos tópicos possuem um formato confuso.
   Entendo obviamente que o formato é adotado em muito países, tal como no Brasil. Mas é um formato confuso.

Particularmente, muitas vezes me confundo com as datas. Eu vejo 10/4, pode ser Outubro ou Abril.

Isso se agrava quando esse tópico está em evidência na home, então dá uma impressão errada de estar lendo algo novo.

Então voltamos ao bot "comunidade". Se foi algo editado pelo "comunidade", então já ficamos cientes que é topico antigo. Sobre isso, como mencionado acima, do ponto de vista do visitante, é inviável. O visitante não faz a menor ideia do que é o usuário "comunidade". Nem eu mesmo sabia das funções desse usuário até algumas semanas atrás.

Um formato mais adequado seria o mês por extenso e abreviado ou usar o padrão ISO 8601.

Enfim, no final de tudo, ainda acho muito confuso o bot comunidade evidenciar os tópicos antigos misturando-os com tópicos novos da home.

O intuito por trás disso, eu não discordo pois é uma ideia boa incentivar a encontrar solução para tais tópicos. Todavia, todo esse esforço traz resultados? É eficiente?

Se provarem com dados estatísticos do sistema administrativo que esse recurso do bot é realmente eficaz, no que se refere a trazer resultados aos tópicos antigos, eu concordaria em manter como está.

Comment: Por que diz "perco tempo respondendo"?

Comment: Adoro navegar no arquivo de perguntas não respondidas atrás de bons desafios. Viva o bot e suas diatribes.

Comment: ramaral, sobre perda de tempo, adicionarei na pergunta o significado.

Comment: Para quem compreende a génese do site uma resposta nunca poderá ser uma "perda de tempo", a não ser que a sua principal motivação seja a obtenção de reputação/pontos.

Comment: acho que vc não leu bem o que escrevi.. e falando sobre pontuação, não dou a mínima para pontuação.. quem conhece o meu histórico aqui, conhece a minha opinião sobre os pontos..

Comment: Julgo que li bem e não encontrei nada que justifique dizer que uma resposta é "perda de tempo". Estou a falar de respostas e não de comentários. O facto de uma pergunta estar "abandonada" pelo AP mas que possa ser respondida, responder nunca será "perda de tempo". No que diz respeito a comentar para pedir esclarecimentos poderá ser ou não "perda de tempo" mas, se a motivação for dar uma resposta, vale a pena tentar.

Comment: Não entendeu mesmo.. porque não faz sentido vc comentar isso dessa forma.. Não foi isso que coloquei.. de forma alguma..

Comment: reli umas 10 vezes o que postei, para ver se deu alguma margem tão séria assim para má interpretação, mas enfim, não sei como consegue interpretar tão mal.. se puder explicar o por quê interpreta dessa forma mostrando os trechos, talvez posso te ajudar a entender.. mas acho desnecessário, pois está tudo muito bem claro..  Saber ler é diferente de saber interpretar..

Comment: Se a intenção é ganhar pontos rápidos, e não tem nada errado com isso, realmente, responder perguntas velhas/abandonadas não é uma boa estratégia. Lá no [so] e [so.meta] já está funcionando a nova homepage, acho que merece uma nova meta-pergunta: "quando a nova *home* vai ser implantada aqui?"

Comment: Um ponto confuso que esqueci de mencionar é o "status". Na home mostra o título da pergunta e logo abaixo "perguntada há X minutos". quando é modificada "modificada há X minutos". Quando o bot evidencia tópico antigo aparece como "modificada há X minutos".. Talvez se pudesse mudar esse status quando é o bot evidenciando topico antigo. Até porque não faz sentido mostrar como "modificado" pois nada foi modificado.. Parece que é uma falta de tradução ou uma gambiarra do sistema..

Comment: para mim não aparece nova homepage... o layout é o mesmo que temos aqui no pt..

Comment: encontrei.. tem que configurar no perfil -> preferências. Nesse artigo fala como fazer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing

Comment: manero!! os caras já estão mechendo. Acho que esse novo design já mataria esse assunto aqui.

Comment: Aquilo que eu quero dizer é que, tal como bem interpretou o @brasofilo, a única razão que eu encontro para dizer que é "perda de tempo" responder a perguntas antigas é se a motivação for ganhar pontos rápidos. Nunca disse que é isso que o motiva a si.

Comment: Pelo que diz Jeff Atwood ([Help us redesign the Stack Overflow homepage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69063/185667)), essa mudança é só para o SO que tem um volume gigantesco de perguntas diárias e não vai ser aplicada no resto da rede. O trabalho do *Community user* não é "gambiarra" e pergunta velha/abandonada **não significa** pergunta inútil. Já existe um monte de jeitos de você filtrar perguntas de acordo com seu interesse e é tipo muito fácil fazer um UserScript para remover essas perguntas que te incomodam na homepage.

Comment: as perguntas em si não incomodam.. o que incomoda é a confusão que traz ao misturar na home com perguntas novas.. isso está explicado no texto..  Em nenhum momento disse que perguntas antigas sejam inúteis.. Acho que também não compreendeu o texto..

Comment: sobre os filtros, novamente, o que descrevi no texto editado da pergunta..  estou sabendo agora que tem filtros.. mas quem disse que vou usar filtro? como que um usuário exporádico vai saber que existe tal recurso? quem fica aqui mais tempo e e conhece bem, pensa que todos deveriam saber..  a maioria é leigo, e eu me incluo nisso pois sou um usuário que acessa exporadicamente.. REpito, um problema aqui é que os recursos em geral não são intuitivos e geram confusão. EStá descrito no texto.. se puderem realmente ler antes de opinar seria interessante..

Comment: @ramaral.. continua sem entender e não responde ao que perguntei.. e também acho que brasofilo não entendeu muito bem não...

Comment: Seu texto é uma dissertação gigante onde nada está muito claro. Suas edições ajudaram muito pouco porque não fez um texto único e coerente, foi juntado idéia encima de idéia. (para notificar outros usários que está lhes respondendo, precisa usar o @nome-do-usuário, o autor do post é sempre notificado)

Comment: `Se provarem com dados estatísticos`, jejeje, é *você* quem tem que provar que o sistema atual é ruim e precisa fundamentar muito bem sua proposta de mudança. Como disse, um texto enorme e todo complexo não ajuda em nada...

Answer (score 11):

O objetivo das perguntas serem colocadas na *home* é justamente as pessoas entrarem nela, se tiver como diferenciar mais do que já diferencia (está escrito que foi o Comunidade que alterou), o objetivo não será cumprido.

Se você tinha uma boa resposta para dar ali, não perdeu tempo algum. Se só olhou, pode ver se tem algo para fazer. Pode aprender algo que não sabia. E se nada disto acontecer, o tempo gasto não será tão grande. E dá para evitar lendo antes quem alterou a pergunta.

Se a resposta é boa, ela é interessante para o site, independente do AP nunca mais voltar lá. Discordo que haja perda de tempo. Mas quem acha que responder estes tópicos é perda de tempo, basta não responder.

Se o *bot* considerou que deve *bumpar* a pergunta é porque ainda não tem uma resposta satisfatória.

Não me parece que outras pessoas estão passando pelo mesmo "problema". Em toda a rede. Pode ter um caso ou outro, mas parece ser uma coisa individual.

Acredito que o novato não está preocupado se ele está perdendo tempo ou não. Se perceber o relatado, ele provavelmente vai perceber que tem informações suficientes

> logo imagino que seja uma pergunta nova

Isto é uma interpretação errada da ferramenta. Todas informações estão disponíveis para ver que a pergunta não é nova até mesmo antes de clicar nela. Dentro dela, fica mais fácil ainda. Dá trabalho responder, verificar se a pergunta é nova ou não, é simples e rápido.

Se você só que ver as perguntas novas, deve acessar esta aba: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest Claro que perderá as atualizações. Pode ser que na nova versão isto fique mais óbvio. Eu acho isto muito fácil de achar, mas se está difícil é uma questão diferente do que foi colocado originalmente na pergunta.

Eu costumo usar esta aba a maior parte do tempo, em alguns momentos eu vou pra *home* pra ver o que está rolando. E de vez em quando eu faço uma revisão geral.

Se existe um problema de usabilidade para melhorar a identificação se a pergunta é nova ou não, é outro assunto diferente do que a pergunta original falava.

Eu acho que precisa ter formas melhores do próprio mecanismo orientar os novatos, mas isto é outro assunto.

Enfim, eu acho que está bom assim. Tem problemas de usabilidade bem mais relevantes e que causam mais "perda de tempo". Este eu acho que causa mais benefícios que malefícios. A SE certamente tem dados que comprovam a eficácia disto.

Comment: entendo a sua resposta, mas não é bem isso não. Adicionarei os arugmentos na pergunta.

Comment: Concordo, e ainda acho que mesmo o argumento de que às vezes as perguntas antigas estão abandonadas e algumas acabam fechadas é um crédito pro *bump*, se uma pergunta não está clara e o Comunidade trouxe de volta pra front page, e depois de tentar conseguir mais detalhes com o AP ela acaba fechada, também não houve perda de tempo alguma.

Comment: @Gabe de fato. Quando é coisa velha que ficou enroscada (o AP não fez a "manutenção" na pergunta, não respondeu os comments, não esclareceu o que faltava) é graças ao _bump_ que eu acabo vendo o problema e voto pra fechar (ou remover, quando é possível e o "conjunto" tem problemas generalizados).

Answer (score 9):

Acredito que não interessa quem perguntou (abandonada) nem quando a pergunta foi feita (velha). E que a intenção é chamar a atenção de:

- público em geral (que visita pela primeira vez),
- interessados em responder,
- editores que podem melhorar um título,
- usuários que podem votar para fechar algo *off-topic* que escapou e permanece aberto,
- outros quaisquer.

Acabo de ver uma pergunta interessante sobre JS e base64 cujas respostas não tinham votos positivos, eram boas, tasquei lá +1. Pode acontecer com uma resposta sua ;)

Solução imediata, coloque isto num [Userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info) e tchau tchau Comunidade na homepage:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        (SOpt) Bye bye, Comunidade
// @match       *://pt.stackoverflow.com/
// ==/UserScript==

$('a[href="/users/-1/comunidade"]').each(function() {
    $(this).parents(".question-summary.narrow").remove()
});
```